# Access SQL Statement Calculate the Difference From Previous Month

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft Access 2016 to developing a new program, each month the data entry enter in a row the date, the total budget plan and cumulative expending amount. I am trying to create a query showing the monthly bases experiences. For example in this month August, the cumulative value 170000, the cumulative value for July 125000, so I need a query showing the difference is 45000.
Attached an Access file for short data examples.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9vlp84fzmjc93d/Minus%20Calculation.accdb?dl=0

Thanks for your support in advance!
Best Regards
Mahmoud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you always want to see the data from exactly one month previous (whether or not such data exists), and that the data could be entered on any day in the month, you might consider the following:

```sql
select 
    t1.date,
    t1.cumulative_expending_amount, 
    t2.cumulative_expending_amount, 
    t1.cumulative_expending_amount-t2.cumulative_expending_amount
from
    YourTable t1 left join YourTable t2 on 
    t1.date >= dateserial(year(t2.date),month(t2.date)+1,1) and
    t1.date <= dateserial(year(t2.date),month(t2.date)+2,0)
```

Change `YourTable`, `date`, and `cumulative_expending_amount` to suit the name of your table and fields respectively.

---

Following your comments, it would appear that the following SQL satisfies your requirements:

```sql
select 
    t1.itemid,
    t1.date,
    t1.cumulative_expending_amount,
    (
        select top 1 t3.cumulative_expending_amount
        from YourTable t3
        where t3.itemid = t1.itemid and t3.date < t1.date
        order by t3.date desc
    ) as last_cumulative_expending_amount,
    t1.cumulative_expending_amount-last_cumulative_expending_amount as diff
from
    YourTable t1 inner join 
    (
        select t.itemid, max(t.date) as mdate
        from YourTable t
        group by t.itemid
    ) t2 on t1.itemid = t2.itemid and t1.date = t2.mdate
order by 
    t1.itemid,
    t1.date desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! This work for exactly month previous, but it seems I forget to add one more detail. I need it to be filtered/grouped by ItemID and minus from previous date data entry for dame ItemID. For example, I have an ItemID called 2222,this ItemID has three entry in different dates, Sep 2018, Jan 2019 and August 2019, so I need max date data entry - previous date data entry group by/filter by ItemID. Thanks for your support!

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I appreciate! The query still returning the all table items and this time without minus the previous month value :(

Comment: this is exactly what i am looking for! thanks for your support and patient!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery.  Based on your description, the code looks like this:

```
select t.*,
       (select top (1) t2.cumulative_spending
        from t as t2
        where t2.date < t.date
        order by t2.date desc
      ) as prev_cumulative_spending
from t;
```